# How To make fluid human model and slowly dissapear?

Tags: fluid-simulation

i've been wondering how to make the scene like image shown
[image: First]
[image: Second]

At the first image, the character is fill with fluid, then the character melt down. Can this scene be done in fluid / flip fluid blender ? Thanks before

Comment: have a look at this section in the manual which shows a video of humanoid figure made and unmade from water https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/physics/fluid/types/control.html not a full tutorial unfortunately